# CSS overlay edit icon for each table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, overlay

I hope some one can help;
I have a table:

```
<tr style="">
  <td width="330" style="vertical-align:top; " class="updater_modus"><span><i class="icon-pencil"></i></span><img src="http://qmail.wm13.de/data/www.douglas.com/95/img/main-image-1-t4_330.jpg" alt=""></td>
  <td width="290" style="padding-top: 20px;padding-left: 20px;padding-right: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;background-color: #ccace6;vertical-align:top; " class="updater_modus">
     <span><i class="icon-pencil"></i></span><p><span style="color: #ffffff;">Hier ein Text!</span></p>
     <p><span style="color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;</span></p>
     <p><span style="color: #ffffff;">...</span></p>
     <p><span style="color: #ffffff;">&nbsp;</span></p>
     <p><span style="color: #ffffff;">...</span></p>
   </td>
</tr>
```

each `td` has an icon. I want the icons be on top left of each icon. Now there are on each `td` an extra space because of the icons.. I hope you know what I mean..

I use class `updater_modus` bad I don't catch the right CSS for it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your table cells `position: relative` and your icons `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0`;